# Group by measure values returned by aggregation

Tags: promql

I am taking maximum value of a measure (`stage`) by group (`instance`) and then I want to show by maximum stage, what is the number of instances.

In SQL, this would be:

```
select max_stage, count(*)
from
  (select instance, max(stage) as max_stage 
   from table 
   group by instance
  ) x
group by 
  max_stage
```

With PromQL, this does not work:

```
count by (stage) ((max by (instance) (stage)))
```

How do I reference max stage in the outer aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `count_values` instead of `count`:

```
count_values ("some_name", max by (instance) (stage))
```

https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators